Why fork print ten times not 7 how compiler do this?
I have this code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int pid = fork();
    fork();    
    if (pid == 0)
    {
      fork();
      fork();
    }
    printf("process ID: %d\n", getpid());
    return 0;
}

I need to know why it's printed 10 times, how we get exactly 10 processes.

This has nothing to do with compilers.

The only correct use of fork should look something like if(pid) { parent(); } else { child(); }. Everything else is very bad program design. Instead of studying badly designed programs, focus on learning good program design.

@Lundin Thank you. I definitely know that, but our professor included this question in the exam, and we didn’t know how it could be 10 processes, so I posted it here because we’re not allowed to ask the professor about exam questions.

You start with one process.
After the first fork, you have two processes, one with a zero pid variable and one with a nonzero pid variable.
Both processes then fork again, so you have four processes, two with a zero pid variable and two with a nonzero pid variable.
At this point, the two processes with the nonzero pid variable skip the if code and fall through to the printf call, then exit.
But the other two processes, with the zero pid variable, both fork again, resulting in four processes with a zero pid variable, then those four processes fork again, resulting in eight processes with a zero pid variable.  Those eight processes then proceed to the printf call, then exit.
So you end up with a total of ten processes.  Two of them have a nonzero pid variable and the other eight have a zero pid variable.

Thanks for replying, my question is why before if become two processes with nonzero, if the parent of all has nonzero and the child has zero, now here become with us two child one for parent and has zero and the other one for first chile and has also zero value, but isn't the first child has zero? or when he went into fork he lost the its firat value?

Ok now I got it, many thanks man

While the answer from Tom is correct, I will add context for why 7 is not correct.
You (like I initially thought) incorrectly assumed the main process is the only process with pid = 0. The following code is what we thought we were doing:
main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int pid = getpid(); // get pid of main process
    fork();
    fork();    
    if (getpid() == pid) // only main process makes this true
    {   
      fork();
      fork();
    }   
    printf("process ID: %d\n", getpid());
    return 0;
}

Compiling and running gives the desired 7 pids.
gcc main.c -o out
./out

stdout
process ID: 81711
process ID: 81710
process ID: 81709
process ID: 81713
process ID: 81714                                                               
process ID: 81712
process ID: 81715

